# Computed array not available in template

Tags: vue.js

I want my array holding records between two given dates to always reflect the chosen from-to dates, but simply returning the response.data from Axios in the **computed** method doesn't seem to do the trick. How can I get the **computed** method to serve the results to the app?

```
<template>
    <div>
      <p v-for="event in events">{{event.title}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "App",
    data () {
        return {}
    },
    computed: {
        fromDate: function() { ..code.. },
        toDate: function() { ..code.. },
        events: function() {
            axios.get('json/' + this.fromDate + '/' + this.toDate).then(response => {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events: function() {
  axios.get('json/' + this.fromDate + '/' + this.toDate)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    });
}
```

First of all, you weren't really returning anything inside that function. And in order to achieve that, you can use the plugin called [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) instead

```
// ...
import AsyncComputed from 'vue-async-computed'

// ...
Vue.use(AsyncComputed)

// ...
asyncComputed: {
  events: function() {
    return axios.get('json/' + this.fromDate + '/' + this.toDate)
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      });
  }
}
```

Using `vue-async-computed` along with ES7 also works:

```
asyncComputed: {
  async events() {
    const response = await axios.get('json/' + this.fromDate + '/' + this.toDate)
    return response.data
  }
}
```

Comment: The "ES7" one still returns a promise and not an actual value and will need that asyncComputed plugin to work.

Comment: Thanks! It works great now. Though I'm still not sure why the original function is not returning anything. The data's there, I can console log it if I use the JSON.stringify function, so why can't it be returned to the events variable? Just curious..